# Nodejs multiple sql query loop

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am pretty new to nodejs and async worlds.

The case is, I have an array like `var ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]`;

I need to update mytable according to sequence of the array element. So I do something like:

```
sort: function(ids, callback) {

 // dont worry about this
  this.create_connection();
  this.connection.connect();

   for(var i=0; i<ids.length;i++) {
      var q = "UPDATE mytable SET sequence="+i+" where id="+ids[i]+"; ";

      this.connection.query(q, function(err, result) {

       // I am not sure about this
       // callback(err);
     });
   }

 // I need to return callback at the end
 // return callback();

  this.connection.end();

}
```

But yes.. it does not work because I have to return callback.. I think I need to do the query syncronously.. I am not sure. Please help thanks.

Comment: why you are not using forEach loop function

Comment: it is synchronous version on for loop

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to async worlds, you should take a look at module 'async'.

You can then do something like this :

```
async.forEachOfSeries(ids, function(id,index,callback){
     var q = "UPDATE mytable SET sequence="+index+" where id="+id+"; ";

      this.connection.query(q, function(err, result) {         
         callback();
     });


},function done(){
    // whatever you want to do onces all the individual updates have been executed.
})
```

Comment: thanks.. where should I initialize and increment the `i` variable ??

Comment: modified the example so you can have the index (use the forEachOf methods)

Answer (score 0):

See my inline comments:

```
sort: function(ids, callback) {
  this.create_connection();
  this.connection.connect();
  var q = "UPDATE mytable SET sequence CASE id ";

  // Don't execute one query per index in ids - that's inefficient
  // Instead, pack up all the queries and execute them at once
  for(var i=0; i<ids.length;i++) {
    q += "WHEN " + ids[i] + " THEN " + i + " ";
  }
  q += "ELSE sequence END;";

  // The sort method will return the result of connection.query
  return this.connection.query(q, function(err, result) {
    // End the connection
    this.connection.end();
    if(err) {
      // Handle any error here
      return callback(err);
    }
    // Otherwise, process, then return the result
    return callback(err, result);
  });
}
```

And here's something slightly more elegant:

```
sort: function(ids, callback) {
  this.create_connection();
  this.connection.connect();

  // Don't execute one query per index in ids - that's inefficient
  // Instead, pack up all the queries and execute them at once
  var q = ids.reduce(function(pv, cv, ci){
    return pv + " WHEN " + cv + " THEN " + ci + " ";
  }, "UPDATE mytable SET sequence CASE id ") + " ELSE sequence END;";

  // The sort method will return the result of connection.query
  return this.connection.query(q, function(err, result) {
    // End the connection
    this.connection.end();
    if(err) {
      // Handle any error here
      return callback(err);
    }
    // Otherwise, process, then return the result
    return callback(err, result);
  });
}
```

And you can replace the `.reduce` in the previous example with the following, if you want to use ES6 arrow functions:

```
var q = ids.reduce((pv, cv, ci) => pv + " WHEN " + cv + " THEN " + ci + " ",
          "UPDATE mytable SET sequence CASE id ") + " ELSE sequence END;";
```

Comment: hi Tex thanks.. I get parse error `{ [Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE mytable  SET sequence=1 where id=1; UPDATE mytable  SET seq' at line 1]
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0 }
`

Comment: You're right - my mysql is pretty rusty. I'll rework the sample code. Apologies for the confusion.