# pass data through the sql response with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

The var caracnamesecurity works great. But when I put a console.log(caracnamesecurity) inside the response of SELECT AVG. It doestn't work anymore.
I don't understand why ..

console.log(results[0])
Console.log(caracnamesecurity) return:

```js
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(rapportqualiteprix)': 2.222222 }
texture f qsf qsd
updated
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(odeur)': 2.088889 }
texture f qsf qsd
updated
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(texture)': 1.022222 }
texture f qsf qsd
```

But I need this:

```js
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(rapportqualiteprix)': 2.222222 }
rapportqualiteprix f qsf qsd
updated
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(odeur)': 2.088889 }
odeur f qsf qsd
updated
RowDataPacket { 'AVG(texture)': 1.022222 }
texture f qsf qsd
```

part of code:

```js
  var avisId = results.insertId
  if (typeof scoreAvis !== 'undefined') {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < scoreAvis.length; i++) {

      if (scoreAvis[i].score > 0){

        var caracnamesecurity = scoreAvis[i].caracname;
        var scoresecurity = scoreAvis[i].score;

        connection.query("UPDATE avis SET " + caracnamesecurity +"="+ scoresecurity +" WHERE avis.id="+ avisId +"", function (error, results, fields) {
          if (!!error) {
            console.log("error avis");
          } else {
            console.log("updated")
          }
        });


        connection.query("SELECT AVG(" + caracnamesecurity + ") FROM avis WHERE products_id=" + req.body[0].id, function (error, results, fields) {

          console.log(results[0])
          console.log(caracnamesecurity + " f qsf qsd ")
          
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: its happening because the function connection.query is async

Comment: @AbhishekAnand hmm.. so What should I do to get the caracname? to put it inside another connection query

Comment: one way(not very efficient) is to use the place both connection query in different for loops.The better way is to use promises.

Comment: hmm okay, I will check how to use promise, thank you

Comment: you might want to check this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830001/nodejs-multiple-sql-query-loop

Comment: @AbhishekAnand I used promise but it was not the problem. I had to use let instead of var, now problem solved. and I did a new promise